# Not able to launch EC2 with Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda

I need spin up a EC2 machine with Lambda function. The lambda function has all the parameters in environment variable set like AMIID, IM_ROLE_NAME etc. When it run the lambda function it gives the error:

```
2018-01-24T06:04:42.189Z    76289722-00cc-11e8-af1d-0bdcfbd45ab7    { InvalidParameterValue: Value (cloudwatchlogs) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/ec2.js:50:35)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
message: 'Value (cloudwatchlogs) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name',
code: 'InvalidParameterValue',
time: 2018-01-24T06:04:42.151Z,
requestId: '4c1e3cae-ba71-45b9-8332-23d6d11b4971',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 43.681361140256826 } null
```

Im not able to resolve the issue above 'Value (cloudwatchlogs) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name',
code: 'InvalidParameterValue',. Please guide.

Comment: Can you put your lambda code as well? The problem is you are passing incorrect value of IAM Role. Once you put the code, we can help better.

Comment: Is `cloudwatchlogs` a role or an instance profile? Does your Lambda have [permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) to use it?

Comment: Thanks everyone i was able to resolve it. The issue was the roles were not accessible to EC2. So i created a new role and that worked. Somehow, the old roles were not visible to Ec2.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it is clear you are specifying an invalid role to the EC2 instance.

In your IAM console, under roles,

1. Verify this role `cloudwatchlogs` exists
2. It has a valid instance profile ARN associated with it

   - On the IAM role page check if the instance profile ARN field is blank, if it is, you need to setup a role correctly which has a valid value in this field. [Read this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)
3. Verify your lambda role has access on the role you are trying to give the EC2. A sample snippet -

   `"Effect": "Allow"
   "Action": "iam:PassRole"
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-id>:role/cloudwatchlogs" or "Resource": "*"`